# QTreeView change selected items’ display text

Tags: python, qt, pyside

How can I change the text displayed in the second column of the rows selected in the treeview when the user hits 'Edit' in the UI? I'm using python and pyside but I'm not clear on how to do this.

What I want to happen is: When user clicks Edit in the UI i would like it to change the text of the selected Treeview Rows second columns. You can just change the text to say 'Hello' or something simple.

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class SortModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SortModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        leftData = self.sourceModel().data(left)
        rightData = self.sourceModel().data(right)

        if leftData:
            leftData = leftData.lower()
        if rightData:
            rightData = rightData.lower()

        print('L:', leftData, 'R:', rightData)
        return leftData < rightData


class Browser(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Browser, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(200, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Assets')
        self.setModal(True)

        self.results = ""

        self.uiItems = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.uiItems.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.uiItems.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.uiItems.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiItems.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiItems.header().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.uiItems.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.uiItems.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self._model = self.create_model(self)
        self._spmodel = SortModel(self)
        self._spmodel.setSourceModel(self._model)
        self._spmodel.setDynamicSortFilter(False)
        self.uiItems.setModel(self._spmodel)

        self.uiEdit = QtGui.QPushButton('Edit')

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.uiItems, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.uiEdit, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.uiItems.doubleClicked.connect(self.doubleClickedItem)
        self.show()

    def doubleClickedItem(self, idx):
        name = idx.data(role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        model = idx.model()
        model.setData(idx, 'great', role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

    def create_model(self, parent):

        items = [
            'Cookie dough',
            'Hummus',
            'Spaghetti',
            'Dal makhani',
            'Chocolate whipped cream'
        ]

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Great'])

        for item in items:

            root = []
            parentNode = QtGui.QStandardItem(item)
            root.append(parentNode)

            # add child row with 2 columns
            for i in range(3):
                row = []
                col1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                col1.setData('COLUMN 1', role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                row.append(col1)
                col2 = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                col2.setData('COLUMN 2', role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                row.append(col2)           
                parentNode.appendRow(row)

            model.appendRow(root)

        return model

    def showEvent(self, event):
        geom = self.frameGeometry()
        geom.moveCenter(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.setGeometry(geom)
        super(Browser, self).showEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            # self.hide()
            self.close()
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(Browser, self).keyPressEvent(event)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Browser()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you want to happen in the GUI when you press the button?

Comment: @eyllanesc updated post to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the button’s [`clicked`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal, retrieve the selected items via [`model.selectedIndexes`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectedIndexes), iterate over them and only handle those with [`.column()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#column)`== 1` as in your `doubleClickedItem` function.

You can also change the [`SelectionBehavior`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop) to only select single items instead of complete rows.